# How to add carriage returns to CSV downloads?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, csv

In reference to this question:
[Google Spreadsheet downloaded as CSV comes out on 1 line?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45705/google-spreadsheet-downloaded-as-csv-comes-out-on-1-line), is there any way to have a downloaded Google Spreadsheets incorporate carriage returns and linefeeds such that if the CSV is opened in Notepad on Windows it appears as multi-line?

Comment: Was my answer of use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Google Developer site, Google Apps Script, the following tutorial can be found: [Interacting With Your Docs List](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial#section3). In section 3, it describes how to save a selected range to CSV.

This particular line of code introduces a carriage return:

```
// Join each row's columns
// Add a carriage return to end of each row, except for the last one
if (row < data.length-1) {
  csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
}
else {
  csv += data[row];
}
```

If you run this script and select a particular range, the CSV file will show up (in notepad) having line breaks:

[image]

I've added the code below and only revised the onOpen script:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var csvMenuEntries = [{name: "Save as CSV file", functionName: "saveAsCSV"}];
  ss.addMenu("CSV", csvMenuEntries);
}

function saveAsCSV() {
  // Prompts the user for the file name
  var fileName = Browser.inputBox("Save CSV file as (e.g. myCSVFile):");

  // Check that the file name entered wasn't empty
  if (fileName.length !== 0) {
    // Add the ".csv" extension to the file name
    fileName = fileName + ".csv";
    // Convert the range data to CSV format
    var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFile_(fileName);
    // Create a file in the Docs List with the given name and the CSV data
    DocsList.createFile(fileName, csvFile);
  }
  else {
    Browser.msgBox("Error: Please enter a CSV file name.");
  }
}

function convertRangeToCsvFile_(csvFileName) {
  // Get the selected range in the spreadsheet
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSelection();
  try {
    var data = ws.getValues();
    var csvFile = undefined;

    // Loop through the data in the range and build a string with the CSV data
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var csv = "";
      for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
            data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
          }
        }

        // Join each row's columns
        // Add a carriage return to end of each row, except for the last one
        if (row < data.length-1) {
          csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
        }
        else {
          csv += data[row];
        }
      }
      csvFile = csv;
    }
    return csvFile;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not keen to get involved with "Development" in relation to Google apps, but if that's the only way, it's the only way ..

Comment: @Paul You have seen that the standard Google export doesn't result in a multi-line CSV format. Under Tools, Script editor, you can add the script. Then press the "bug" button to authenticate the script.

Comment: Aye aye, can't properly assess your answer where I am now, I'm sure I'll be accepting when I get home. Thankyou. (Edit: Annoyingly I can't even up-vote at 13rep)

Comment: @Paul solved !!

Comment: Hoped you'd take the hint :p